# How to select multiple tables column matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Work in sql server 2014.Want a question-ans management application.My application have bellow table structure.Stuck on **sql query** how to select template 1 questions and answers. Is there any better approach ,please share with me.

[image]

Sample demo inputs are :

```
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestionAns] ([QuestionAnsId], [Question], [Ans]) VALUES (1, N'Hello?', N'Hello')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestionAns] ([QuestionAnsId], [Question], [Ans]) VALUES (2, N'World?', N'World')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestionAns] ([QuestionAnsId], [Question], [Ans]) VALUES (3, N'Animal?', N'Animal')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestionAns] ([QuestionAnsId], [Question], [Ans]) VALUES (4, N'Ocean?', N'Ocean')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestionAns] ([QuestionAnsId], [Question], [Ans]) VALUES (5, N'Human?', N'Human')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestionTemplate] ([QuestionTemplateId], [Q1], [Q2], [Q3], [Q4], [Q5]) VALUES (1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestionTemplate] ([QuestionTemplateId], [Q1], [Q2], [Q3], [Q4], [Q5]) VALUES (2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 4)
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do want the following result?

```
SELECT tt.QuestionTemplateId,qa.Question,qa.Ans FROM tblQuestionTemplate AS tt
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(Q1),(Q2),(Q3),(Q4),(Q5)) c(Q)
INNER JOIN tblQuestionAns AS qa ON qa.QuestionAnsId=c.Q
```

```
QuestionTemplateId  Question    Ans
1   Hello?  Hello
1   Animal? Animal
1   Human?  Human
1   Ocean?  Ocean
1   World?  World
2   Hello?  Hello
2   Human?  Human
2   Animal? Animal
2   World?  World
2   Ocean?  Ocean
```